# Return Joi external validation error with other errors

Tags: node.js, validation, async-await, joi

I am struggeling with external() method. I have own validation thich checks that login is exist in db. But my own validation error do not return with others

e.g. If password & confirmedPassword don't match the Joi validation is informing about that but not about isLoginTaken. After corrected password matches the isLoginTaken error will be returned

Is it possible to return all errors together ??

##### Own Validation method

```
const checkIsExistLogin = (login) => {
  const isLoginExist = UserModel.exists({ login }) 

  if (isLoginExist !== null) {
    throw new Joi.ValidationError(
      'string.login',
      [
        {
          message: 'login exist',
          path: ['login'],
          type: 'string.login',
          context: {
            key: 'login',
            label: 'login',
            login,
          },
        },
      ],
      login
    )
  }
}
```

##### Export & Invoke validateAsync func

```
export const validateUser = (user) =>
  JoiSchema.validateAsync(user, { abortEarly: false })
```

##### Route controller

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await validateUser(req.body)

    let user = new User({
      name: req?.body?.name,
      lastName: req?.body?.lastName,
      birthDate: req?.body?.birthDate,
      pin: req?.body?.pin,
      adress: req?.body?.adress,
      login: req?.body?.login,
      password: req?.body?.password,
      passwordConfirmation: req?.body?.passwordConfirmation,
    })

    user = await user.save()

    return res.json({
      success: true,
      data: user,
      message: "You've added new user",
    })
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      data: [],
      message: error,
    })
  }
})
```

I'll be glad for any tips.

Comment: The quoting error `'You've added new user'` is on purpose?

Comment: No, I corrected it

Comment: @Marc Do u think is it possible ??

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking if you can return all the errors together, then I have an option for you that it's out of the box.

1. Make a map that will have all the errors that you will throw:

   ```
   const errorMap = new Map();
   ```
2. If one of the parts of your code gives you an error or you want to throw an
   error there, then add the Error to the Map:

   Con try/catch:

   ```
   try {
       throw new Error("Hello");
   } catch (e) {
       errorMap.set("HelloError",e);
   }
   ```

   Normal (Is the same for Joi in this case, just use the error variable instead):

   ```
   const HelloError = new Error("Hello");
   errorMap.set("HelloError",HelloError);
   ```
3. Once you have your validations done, then you have to check if there is any errors by checking the size of the map, and if thats the case throw it like an error and catch it were you want to display the errors:

   ```
   try {
       if (errorMap.size > 0) {
           throw errorMap;
       }
   } catch (e) {
       console.log(e);
   }
   ```
4. Now you can do whatever you want to do with the map, throw an error being the message a list of the validations errors that you found, for example.